# Trouble running npm start on new react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have created react apps multiple times before and never had problems with it. Now however I run

1. npm init react-app name (and it creates the app)
2. cd name
3. npm start

At three is where I get the problem... Nothing happens.
I have tried creating 3 apps now and always have the same problem. I have tried deleting all node_modules and package-lock.json and then running npm install, but when I run npm start nothing happens. What could it be? Please help me. I am trying to solve what should be much more challenging problems and really didn't expect to lose so much time with this issue.

I very recently upgraded my mac from sierra to mojave. PErhaps that has something to do with this?

By running npm start --verbose I get this:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.12.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'start',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.4

npm info using node@v13.12.0
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0~prestart: my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0~start: my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0~start: ignored because ignore-scripts is set to true my-rea
ct-tutorial-app@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0~poststart: my-react-tutorial-app@0.1.0
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 159ms
npm info ok
```

Comment: node issues are frequent after mac update, checkout this link https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md

Comment: I am using CRA with command `npx create-react-app my-app` on Mojave, faced no issues so far.

Comment: I tried with npx create-react-app my-react-app but it gives me exactly the same problem. package.json contains start script as it should.

Comment: I solved the problem. Somehow I had ignore scripts set to true in npm

Comment: I solved it already but yes that is what was wrong. Thanks.